# Suddenly stopped showing my wifi in ubuntu 14.04 in the list in Dell Inspiron 5420?

Tags: wireless, 14.04, inspiron

Suddenly stopped showing my wifi in ubuntu 14.04 in the list in Dell Inspiron 5420,googled a lot,could not go through a working solution.Any Ubuntu user faced the same,please help me?
https://askubuntu.com/.../only-my-wifi-is-not-working... This thread have the similar problem but it is not working.
Earlier It was working as perfect,don't know what happened!

Comment: I know that you probably looked at this, but did you accidently press the keys that turn off the wireless device?

Comment: Also, try booting an older kernel

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>