# Wifi not working in ubuntu 14.04 all of a sudden

Tags: wireless, 14.04, networking

My wifi is not detecting any wifi connections although they are present.

As soon as I start my system Network Disconnected notification shows up. But it happens to work sometime and it is quiet strange.

Also there is no option to enable wifi in the wifi options like it is for enable networking.

Other people also have reported similar issues:
[Suddenly stopped showing my wifi in ubuntu 14.04 in the list in Dell Inspiron 5420?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485621/suddenly-stopped-showing-my-wifi-in-ubuntu-14-04-in-the-list-in-dell-inspiron-54)

I have run the diagnosis at [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Below is the report :

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 26 Aug 2014 12:37 IST +0530

Script from: 17 Aug 2014 02:46 UTC +0000

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop #####

Ubuntu

##### lspci #####

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM [8086:155a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:05de]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

##### lsusb #####

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0461:4d51 Primax Electronics, Ltd 0Y357C PMX-MMOCZUL (B) [Dell Laser Mouse]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #####

dell_wmi               12761  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
wmi                    19177  1 dell_wmi

##### interfaces #####

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig #####

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC addr eth0>  
          inet addr:10.0.0.53  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::eef4:bbff:fe19:f33c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:328153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:188224 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30083070 (30.0 MB)  TX bytes:14284753 (14.2 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7f00000-f7f20000 

##### iwconfig #####

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search web2labs.com

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Ethernet connection 1] ----------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC addr eth0>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.0.0.53
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         10.0.0.1

    DNS:             10.0.0.1

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels #####

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #####

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos #####

##### module parameters #####

##### /etc/modules #####

lp
rtc
acpiphp

##### blacklists #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-i915-hsw.conf]
blacklist i915_hsw

##### udev rules #####

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x8086:0x155a (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC addr eth0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x08b1 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
# USB device 0x:0x (cdc_ether)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

##### dmesg #####

[    1.299759] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.3.2-k
[    1.463135] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[   18.312061] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[   18.434935] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Your wireless card is not showing up, so it is either going out or is not connected good, or possibly you can reset the bios or change a setting in the bios to make the wireless show up. But as long as it is not detected installing a new driver or nothing else will work. My card went out in my laptop last year, I had to buy an usb adaptor.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This laptop being my work machine. I do not have access to open or reset the bios. But tapping on the sides of the laptop has connected the wifi back. Must be a loose connection. Should get this fixed permanently. Thanks a lot for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

All users on network are getting continuously connected-disconnect, or not getting detetcting your wifi driver?

You are saying that it was connected before. So please check what you have added new in the system. I have faced issues with wifi getting continuously because of WIFI frequency conflict with other wifi router's. Which is resolved by setting "Select Auto channel" mode in router.

Also go to software & updates, and check the settings, that will also cause the wifi driver's issues.

Regards,
Santosh

Comment: No it is fine for others. I am not able to see Enable wifi option in the internet options dropdown in the header. I did not install new anything new lately but I suspended the system a lot of times. Not sure if that could have caused problems.

Comment: Please try to update the repository. And see if it gets resolved, or else if you have wired connectivity to your system, I would like to take a look at it for once.